# pinescript backtest different time

Tags: pine-script

i have a strategy but i have a problem

this strategy will send alert when candle close , but in backtest and on chart , order is on candle open price!

can anyone help me to solve these problem?

you can test this problem with tradingview reply
I try so many things but I wasn't successful

I want to get alert same as chart in open price

or if it is not possible , see backtest result with close price , same as alert

my strategy code:

```
//@version=3
//

strategy(title = "Open Close Cross Strategy R5.1 revised by JustUncleL", shorttitle = "OCC Strategy R5.1", overlay = true, 
  pyramiding = 0, overlay=true , default_qty_value=100 , initial_capital=100 , default_qty_type=strategy.cash, calc_on_every_tick=false)

// === INPUTS ===
useRes      = input(defval = true, title = "Use Alternate Resolution?")
intRes      = input(defval = 3,    title = "Multiplier for Alernate Resolution")
stratRes    = ismonthly? tostring(interval*intRes,"###M") : isweekly? tostring(interval*intRes,"###W") : isdaily?  tostring(interval*intRes,"###D") : isintraday ? tostring(interval*intRes,"####") : '60'
basisType   = input(defval = "SMMA", title = "MA Type: ", options=["SMA", "EMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "HullMA", "LSMA", "ALMA", "SSMA", "TMA"])
basisLen    = input(defval = 8, title = "MA Period", minval = 1)
offsetSigma = input(defval = 6, title = "Offset for LSMA / Sigma for ALMA", minval = 0)
offsetALMA  = input(defval = 0.85, title = "Offset for ALMA", minval = 0, step = 0.01)
scolor      = input(false, title="Show coloured Bars to indicate Trend?")
delayOffset = input(defval = 0, title = "Delay Open/Close MA (Forces Non-Repainting)", minval = 0, step = 1)
tradeType   = input("BOTH", title="What trades should be taken : ", options=["LONG", "SHORT", "BOTH", "NONE"])
// === /INPUTS ===

// Constants colours that include fully non-transparent option.
green100 = #008000FF
lime100  = #00FF00FF
red100   = #FF0000FF
blue100  = #0000FFFF
aqua100  = #00FFFFFF
darkred100 = #8B0000FF
gray100 = #808080FF

// === BASE FUNCTIONS ===
// Returns MA input selection variant, default to SMA if blank or typo.
variant(type, src, len, offSig, offALMA) =>
    v1 = sma(src, len)                                                  // Simple
    v2 = ema(src, len)                                                  // Exponential
    v3 = 2 * v2 - ema(v2, len)                                          // Double Exponential
    v4 = 3 * (v2 - ema(v2, len)) + ema(ema(v2, len), len)               // Triple Exponential
    v5 = wma(src, len)                                                  // Weighted
    v6 = vwma(src, len)                                                 // Volume Weighted
    v7 = 0.0
    v7 := na(v7[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (v7[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len    // Smoothed
    v8 = wma(2 * wma(src, len / 2) - wma(src, len), round(sqrt(len)))   // Hull
    v9 = linreg(src, len, offSig)                                       // Least Squares
    v10 = alma(src, len, offALMA, offSig)                               // Arnaud Legoux
    v11 = sma(v1,len)                                                   // Triangular (extreme smooth)
    // SuperSmoother filter
    // © 2013  John F. Ehlers
    a1 = exp(-1.414*3.14159 / len)
    b1 = 2*a1*cos(1.414*3.14159 / len)
    c2 = b1
    c3 = (-a1)*a1
    c1 = 1 - c2 - c3
    v12 = 0.0
    v12 := c1*(src + nz(src[1])) / 2 + c2*nz(v12[1]) + c3*nz(v12[2])
    type=="EMA"?v2 : type=="DEMA"?v3 : type=="TEMA"?v4 : type=="WMA"?v5 : type=="VWMA"?v6 : type=="SMMA"?v7 : type=="HullMA"?v8 : type=="LSMA"?v9 : type=="ALMA"?v10 : type=="TMA"?v11: type=="SSMA"?v12: v1

// security wrapper for repeat calls
reso(exp, use, res) => use ? security(tickerid, res, exp, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : exp

// === /BASE FUNCTIONS ===

// === SERIES SETUP ===
closeSeries     = variant(basisType, close[delayOffset], basisLen, offsetSigma, offsetALMA)
openSeries      = variant(basisType, open[delayOffset], basisLen, offsetSigma, offsetALMA)
// === /SERIES ===

// === PLOTTING ===

// Get Alternate resolution Series if selected.
closeSeriesAlt = reso(closeSeries, useRes, stratRes)
openSeriesAlt = reso(openSeries, useRes, stratRes)
//
trendColour = (closeSeriesAlt > openSeriesAlt) ? green : red
buying = (closeSeriesAlt > openSeriesAlt) ? true : false
selling = (closeSeriesAlt < openSeriesAlt) ? true : false
bcolour     = (closeSeries > openSeriesAlt) ? lime100 : red100
barcolor(scolor?bcolour:na, title = "Bar Colours")
closeP=plot(closeSeriesAlt, title = "Close Series", color = trendColour, linewidth = 2, style = line, transp = 20)
openP=plot(openSeriesAlt, title = "Open Series", color = trendColour, linewidth = 2, style = line, transp = 20)
fill(closeP,openP,color=trendColour,transp=80)

// === /PLOTTING ===
//

//
// === ALERT conditions
xlong       = crossover(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt) 
xshort      = crossunder(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt)
longCond    = xlong   // alternative: longCond[1]? false : (xlong or xlong[1]) and close>closeSeriesAlt and close>=open
shortCond   = xshort  // alternative: shortCond[1]? false : (xshort or xshort[1]) and close<closeSeriesAlt and close<=open
// === /ALERT conditions.

// === STRATEGY ===
// stop loss
slPoints    = input(defval = 0, title = "Initial Stop Loss Points (zero to disable)", minval = 0)
tpPoints    = input(defval = 0, title = "Initial Target Profit Points (zero for disable)", minval = 0)
// Include bar limiting algorithm
ebar            = input(defval = 10000, title="Number of Bars for Back Testing", minval=0)
dummy           = input(false,        title="- SET to ZERO for Daily or Longer Timeframes" )
//
// Calculate how many mars since last bar
tdays       = (timenow-time)/60000.0  // number of minutes since last bar
tdays       := ismonthly? tdays/1440.0/5.0/4.3/interval : isweekly? tdays/1440.0/5.0/interval : isdaily? tdays/1440.0/interval : tdays/interval // number of bars since last bar
//
//set up exit parameters
TP = tpPoints>0?tpPoints:na
SL = slPoints>0?slPoints:na

// Make sure we are within the bar range, Set up entries and exit conditions
startDate = input(1 , title="Start Date")
startMonth = input(1, title="Start Month")
startYear = input(2020 , title="Start Year" )

endDate = input(30 , title="End Date")
endMonth = input(12 , title="End Month")
endYear = input( 2022  ,title="End Year")


inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,
         startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))

if (inDateRange)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when=buying )
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, when=selling )
    //strategy.close("long", when =selling)
    //strategy.close("short", when = buying)
    //strategy.exit("XL", from_entry = "long", profit = TP, loss = SL)
    //strategy.exit("XS", from_entry = "short", profit = TP, loss = SL)

// === /STRATEGY ===
// eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Sir, strategy calculations are made on close and just as your alert comes through at close, confirmation of a signal too comes it at candle close. Thus this signal is not actionable until next available price, the next available sale, which is first tick of the bar following. Just as you would get an alert and go enter a trade on the next bar, so too would the strategy, so the emulator calculates it as such. This is not exclusive to TradingView, this is the nature and expected behaviour of backtesting as a whole.

Cheers